# raising exceptions issue

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
class longInputException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, length, max):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.length = len(length)
        self.max = max

try:
    max = 3
    s = raw_input('Enter something-->')
    if len(s) > max:
        raise longInputException(s, max)

except longInputException, x:
    print 'longInputException: the input was of length %d, \
was expecting less than or equal to %d' % (x.length, x.max)

else:
    print 'No exception was raised.'
```

What I don't understand is why `x` is used in the `longInputException`'s `except` statement. why not just used `self` in the substitution tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is the name of the current object **within** `__init__()` method (because you have provided `self` as the first argument in `__init__()`'s definition), it is not accessible outside of it.

Optionally you can do something like that (although this is **not** something you should do, as this may confuse people about which variable is which):

```
except longInputException, self:
    print 'longInputException: the input was of length %d, \
was expecting less than or equal to %d' % (self.length, self.max)

else:
    print 'No exception was raised.'
```

Does it answer your question?

You can learn more about that by reading about closures and namespaces in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If your try...except statements were in an instantiation of another class and you used "self" in the except statement, "self" would refer to the instantiated class, not the instantiated exception class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because then you wouldn't know which instance of the exception you were referring to.  You typically only use 'self' inside objects anyways.